# Javascript return String to Html

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner question:
I would like to pass in window.location.hash to my form action parameter.  How can I do this with a javascript call?

my current non-working code is:

```
<form method="POST"
    action="j_security_check"+window.location.hash>
```

Comment: use onload: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add/update an attribute to an HTML element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript needs to be based on some kind of event. So you might want to do it when your submit button is pressed or something:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.action = 'j_security_check'+window.location.hash" />

.....
```

Comment: -1 The javascript doesn't need to be based on any event to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="hello" method="POST" action="">
    Hello
</form>​

<script>
    document.forms.hello.action = 'j_security_check'+window.location.hash;
    alert(document.forms.hello.action);
</script>
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/2QE6h/1