# HTML Custom Attributes and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to add a custom HTML attribute to say a DIV element and then be able to use CSS attribute selectors with it in IE?

Example that works (turns into green) in FF but not in IE:

in JavaScript:

```
element.setAttribute('newAttr', 'green');
```

in CSS:

```
[newAttr=green] {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript

Above link is provide the answer for you...

Comment: @Ksnrg: I am really interested in accessing these created attributed using CSS attribute selectors in IE

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<div id="some" data-newattr="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var attribute = document.createAttribute("size");
attribute.nodeValue = "15"
document.getElementById("text").setAttributeNode(attribute);
```

Comment: For some reason, I tried that with CSS attribute selectors in IE and it does not work!