# Set data attribute on div with js

Tags: javascript

I've got a bunch of div.textBox that I want to apply data attribute to it.

Here's what I want to end up with :

```
<div class="text" data-stellar-ratio="2">
```

I've tried :

```
document.getElementByClassName('text').dataset.stellar.ratio = "2";
```

But it's not working...

Help!

Comment: Try `element.setAttribute('data-stellar-ratio', 'something');`

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript

Comment: Should probably be `.dataset.stellarRatio = '2';`

Comment: Isn't it `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: It is a lot easier to manipulate the DOM with the help of jQuery,
$(".text").attr('data-stellar-ratio', '2'); But I'm not sure that you want an answer with jQuery in it.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('text').dataset.stellarRatio = "2";` did not work. Though it worked with `getElementById` .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an
> array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
> class name(s).

More precisely, a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is returned and can be accessed as an array. The first element the selector finds is accessed via index 0.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].setAttribute('data-stellar-ratio', '2')
```

Answer (score 2):

You spelled `getElementsByClassName` wrong and you need to iterate over the collection of elements and change `stellar.ration` to `stellarRatio`.

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (var x = 0; x < eles.length; x++){
  eles[x].dataset.stellarRatio = "2";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

setAttribute doesn't quite work in all browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp has an example that will certainly work well.

```
var att=document.createAttribute("whatever");
att.value="someting";
document.getElementById('mydivid').setAttributeNode(att);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add data attribute to any element in html using the following statement:

> $('#id_of_element').attr('data-id', 'your_value');

It will render as follows for a div:

```
<div data-id="your_value">
```

Comment: it will not work with pure Javascript. It requires jQuery