# how to get javascript variable in inline style

Tags: javascript, styles, inline

i want to use a javascript variable screen as style backgroundattribute in a inline style declaration.

```
<div id ="content" style=" position: relative; top: -400px;  left: 0px;  width: 60px; height: 400px; z-index: 901;background-image: url(' + screen + ') "></div>
```

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.write('<div id ="content"
  style="
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 901;
    background-image: url(' + screen + ')
  ">
</div>')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = screen;
```

Comment: i wondered if it could be done as in my code but it cant i presume.