# What is wrong with my javascript for a browser I would like to create?

Tags: javascript, browser

I know you people will think I am insane, and thus an idiot, but I really have a serious question, well at least to me. What is wrong with my javascript for a browser I would like to create?It will not open the URL in the iframe. I am creating an html source file with some javascript to split a "get" url,and echo the resulting variable into an iFrame. I wanna use Webkit as the rendering engine, so I'm using Google Chrome to create an application shortcut. Yes, I know it will require google chrome, but this is just a test.

```
function goTo(){
var urlb = window.location.href;
var urla =  urlb.split('localhost/browser.html?url=');
var urlc = urla[1];
var urld = urlc.replace("+"," ");
var urle = urld.replace("%3A ",":");
var urlg = urle.replace("%2F","/");
var url = urlg;
document.getElementByID('url').innerHTML="<iframe src=' . url . "'width='100%' 
height='90%'></iframe> Opened:"  . url ."</div>";
}
```

This is the javscript function to open the url. I am pretty sure you would think that the html is just a simple input form and the blank Iframe, which it is.

Please help me if you can.

Comment: In order to know what is "wrong", we need to understand what it does that it shouldn't or what it doesn't that it should.

Comment: Never mind.. I still am having technical difficulties

Comment: @Satpal That should represent var url.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I revised it. It will not write the to the iframe

Comment: First of all, the concatenation character in JS is `+`, not `.`. Secondly the quotes are all over the place.

Comment: Wasn't this question deleted a moment ago?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to get the URL, you want to use `decodeURIComponent()`.  Don't make up your own function to unescape the data.  Also, get the query string parameters properly.  See this StackOverflow post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/362536

Now that you have the proper URL, don't simply inject it into your HTML.  You're opening yourself up to security troubles, and a broken browser when you run into characters you don't expect.  Create the iframe, then set its attributes programmatically.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/710347/362536

Finally, fix your syntax errors.