# Change HTML5 data attribute when updating an input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use some javascript to update a data-attribute (data-foo) associated with a div when entering text into an input field. Any ideas? I'm totally stumped.

```
<div data-foo=""></div>
<textarea name="extraoptions">bar</textarea>
```

Comment: May it be jQuery? - Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned im trying to do this using jquery but im stuck solving this seemingly basic procedure.

Comment: You simply assign to the div's *data-foo* attribute. How you reference the div is up to you, but along the lines of: `div.setAttribute('data-foo',textarea.value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just code for you in my FIDDLE. Use this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/f7A7w/). It will work properly. I hope this is the one you want now.

**HTML5**

```
<input id="text" type="text"/>
<br/><br/>
<div id="result" data-foo="">This is the div with `data-foo` attribute. While you typing this div `data-foo` attribute will change as input valu. If you want to check it. Just click on below button.</div>
<br/>
<button id="test">What is my DIV `data-foo` now?</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
//FOR TESTING - This function will help you to test the below function is working or not
$("#test").click(function(){
    var value = $('#result').attr('data-foo');
    alert(value);
});

//This function will auto change `data-foo` while you typing 
$("#text").keyup(function(){
   var text = $(this).val();
   $("#result").attr('data-foo',text);
});
```

Use it when `DOM` is ready.

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do something like this:

```
jQuery("body").find("div[data-foo]").html('My New HTML Content For DIV with data-foo attribute');
```

So, why use:

```
jQuery("body")
```

Opposed to:

```
$("body")
```

You may ask? Well, this makes sure we don't get any conflicts with any other libraries that might be in use on a site, consider it a safe way of writing jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get this div by id or by class, lets say

```
<div id="div1" data-foo=""></div>
```

then you can do this -

```
$("#div1").attr("data-foo", val)
```