# create div horizontal layout element dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How can I create `<div horizontal layout></div>` element dynamically using javascript?

i can create div element with document.createElement("div"); but how do I add horizontal layout to it?

Comment: After creating element, you can add class name to the element. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Comment: but that is not a class, i know how to set attributes, but it doesn't work there

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal layout? Can you put some more details?

Comment: i want to create this element dynamically <div horizontal layout></div>

Comment: What about `.setAttribute()` function?

Comment: Another work around is get parent element and append string "<div horizontal layout></div>" using innerHtml

Comment: .setAttribute() requires two arguments

Comment: would work if tags had blank tags? like horizontal='' and layout=''? The better practice is innerHTML, indeed.

Comment: how about document.createAttribute

Comment: could you give me an example with innerHtml? don't really know what you mean

Comment: Ok, createAttribute looks to work. TY. I'll try to give an example.

Comment: how does createAttribute works? How do i set this attribute to my div after I created it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.setAttribute('horizontal', '');
newdiv.setAttribute('layout', '');
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
// You can insertBefore() too.

// Or... document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<div horizontal layout></div>';

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Some helpful links:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

[Adding elements to the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml)

[Searching elements in DOM](http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom)

[How to add or update an attribute to an HTML element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript)

And so on.

Comment: Mark as answer then ;P
Have a nice day.