# Javascript getElementById attribute has hypen

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Everything works fine if I use the attribute "value".

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "Email already exists."
```

But when I try to use an attribute that has a hypen "-" on it, it doesn't work anymore

```
document.getElementById("email").data-error = "Email already exists."
```

I've tried variations like `['data-error']` or ."data-error" but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Comment: See also [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: You haven’t even tried `setAttribute`?

Comment: Also duplicate of [How to add/update an attribute to an HTML element using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/710275/2074608)

Answer (score 0):

To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

In your case, if you want to set a value to data attribute:

```
document.getElementById("email").dataset.error = "Email already exists."
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a text field, value attribute can be accessed in two ways by directly calling

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "Email already exists."
```

and by using setAttribute.

```
document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("value", "value of text field");
```

so to set an attribute value of data-error we need use it as

```
document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("data-error", "Email already exists.");
```

and get the attribute value is by

```
document.getElementById("email").getAttribute("data-error");
```