# Set an attribute to the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

I want to echo something inside the div tag using javascript to show this way

```
<div class="content" something></div>
```

I need it using javascript because I want to use a function to echo something if the screen is wider than 960px
I used this answer for the second part [Do something if screen width is less than 960 px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px)

Thanks guy in advance.

Comment: you are looking for set custom Attribute right?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That called `attribute`, to set attribute you could use the methods below.

Pure JS **[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** method :

```
element.setAttribute('name','value');
```

jQuery **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method :

```
$(element).attr('name','value');
```

**Example :**

```
document.querySelector('.content').setAttribute('something',''); //Pure JS
//Or
$('.content').attr('something',''); //jQuery
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps a data attribute would have been appropriate, i.e. `data-something="foo"`

Comment: Perhaps @AndFisher but it may also a `title` or another global Attribute.

Comment: Perhaps, but I think the distinction between valid attributes and custom data attributes  is worth mentioning

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('.content').attr('something','');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the attribute if window width is greater then 960

```
if ( window.innerWidth > 960 ) {

    document.querySelector('.content').setAttribute('something','')

}
```

Comment: You missed the semi-colon.

Comment: Javascript doesn't require semi-colon.