# I'm trying to get the innerHTML of all <h2> tags and set that as their individual IDs but I'm not sure how to go about it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a bunch of `<h2>` tags and without going into detail, I can't manually assign them IDs. So I THINK I could use `.innerhtml` to somehow get the `<h2>` text and assign that as IDs for them but I'm not sure how to get started.

Is this even possible?

The html would look something like this:

```
<body>
   <h2>Science</h2>
   <h2>History</h2>
   <h2>Mathematics</h2>

   <script>

   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Bit of an XY Problem here. You don't use `innerHTML` to set the attribute of an element.

Comment: Why do you think that the `<h2>` elements *need* an `id` property/attribute? What are you doing with them that requires that property/attribute to be there? Incidentally, to the point that Heretic Monkey has raised, you may wish to read this page: "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set an attribute to the div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220068/set-an-attribute-to-the-div-tag)

Comment: Note that if the `h2` contains spaces and/or HTML, you may have issues with taking the content verbatim.

Comment: Please consider using `textContent` for this. `innerHTML` is rarely what you actually need; in this case, of setting the text content to an element's Id, I'd definitely use the `textContent` property.

Comment: @ndugger Seems like using `innerText` would be better in the case that the `h2` elements contain markup.. also `textContent`'s compatibility is about identical to `innerText`'s it's just not supported by IE 9; it is supported by IE 10 (which most IE users are using nowadays)

Comment: @user1538301 I doubt you want markup in your Ids, so no, I'd still recommend `textContent`. `innerText` was non-standard for a long time, and was only adopted by chrome for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @ndugger how is it non-standard when its supported in all major browsers? And innerText wouldn't give you markup, it would give you the text as it would appear if copied by a user. It seems like your knowledge of JS is bit outdated.

Comment: @ndugger in fact, here is the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute). It was adopted by Chrome to stay compliant with the standard.

Comment: @user1538301 It was added to the standard in 2016, and then Chrome adopted it. Before then it was non-standard, but now we're both just being pedantic, so let's end it there.

Comment: @ndugger one of us is being pedantic, one of us is just spreading misinformation and presenting it as fact. If we were both being pedantic it would actually be productive as we'd eventually get to the conclusion of the matter, accuracy does matter on StackOverflow, but I will leave you to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203613/discussion-between-user1538301-and-ndugger).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will want to use the DOM to find all the h2 elements and process accordingly:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Science</h2>
    <h2>History</h2>
    <h2>Mathematics</h2>

    <script>
        var h2s = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
        h2s.forEach(function(h2Element) {
          h2Element.id = h2Element.innerText;
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*As the comments have said, you should avoid using `innerHTML` unless you are sure you want the HTML content of the element - Using `innerText` instead will make sure you only receive the plaintext*

---

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all of the `h2` elements in an HTMLCollection

You can then simply loop over this and update the property directly by using:

```js
ele.id = ele.innerText;
```

Or you can make use of `setAttribute` like this:

```js
ele.setAttribute('id', ele.innerText);
```

.

*You might also want to use `.toLowerCase()` after the innerHTML, just to have a more standard ID styling*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach((ele) => {
  ele.id = ele.innerText;
});

console.log(document.getElementById('History').innerText);
```

```html
<body>
   <h2>Science</h2>
   <h2>History</h2>
   <h2>Mathematics</h2>

   <script>

   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: In the case where there is HTML in the `h2` element, this (`innerHTML) will set the attribute to something like "&lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;" for an `h2` like `<h2><b>bold</b></h2>` which is perhaps not what the OP is looking for. I would use `innerText` instead, but would first get clarification from the OP what to do in the case of HTML elements, spaces, and other characters not allowed in attributes first.

Comment: I did think this, and was going to add something at the bottom about using innerText instead - But figured I could leave it as it is in case the OP's case is with data that w on't be an issue; I'll edit this if OP clarifies as you say

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this suggestion - I've also added a brief explanation for OP as to why `innerText` is being used, just for extra clarity. Even though I assume the comments from others will be suffice

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Light.